# Hi! how can i go into the layout which i selected from the spinner?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have three options to choose from the spinner, if i choose (e.g: "choose mode") and click the next button to send me in to the layout i selected, 
and so on, i' m thinking to use switch cases, but i don't know how to do it exactly

```
    public class ParkingModeActivity extends Activity {

        private Spinner spinner1;
        private Button btnNext;

        private Button btnLedControl;

        private int temp = 0;

        private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
        private BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = null;
        private BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
        private OutputStream outStream = null;

        private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

        private String address = null;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_parking_mode);

            btnNext           = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_next);

            Intent intent = getIntent();
            this.address = intent.getStringExtra("pairedMac");

            addListenerOnButton();
            addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection();


            btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
            checkBTState();

            btnLedControl = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_ledControl);

            btnLedControl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    switch (temp){
                        case 0:
                            sendData("1");
                            Toast msg = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                                    "LED IS ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            msg.show();
                            temp++;
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            sendData("0");
                            Toast msg2 = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                                    "LED IS OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            msg2.show();
                            temp--;
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() {
            spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        }

        public void addListenerOnButton() {

            spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
            btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_next);

            btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    switch (temp) {

                        case 0:
                            if (btnNext.equals(spinner1) {

                                Intent intent = new Intent(ParkingModeActivity.this, ChooseMode.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }

                    }

                    Toast.makeText(ParkingModeActivity.this,
                            "OnClickListener : " +
                                    "\nSpinner 1 : " + String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem()),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            });

        }


        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();

            Log.d("SEND BT SERIAL", "In onResume - Attempting client connect");

            BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);

            try {
                btSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onResume() and socket create failed: " + e.getMessage() + ".");
            }

            btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

            Log.d("SEND BT SERIAL", "Connecting to Remote");
            try {
                btSocket.connect();
                Log.d("SEND BT SERIAL", "Connection established and data link opened...");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                try {
                    btSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e2) {
                    errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onResume() and unable to close socket during connection failure" + e2.getMessage() + ".");
                }
            }

            Log.d("SEND BT SERIAL", "Creating Socket");

            try {
                outStream = btSocket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onResume() and output stream creation failed:" + e.getMessage() + ".");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            super.onPause();

            Log.d("SEND BT SERIAL", "In onPause()");

            if (outStream != null) {
                try {
                    outStream.flush();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onPause() and failed to flush output stream: " + e.getMessage() + ". Unplug bluetooth module and then plug back.");
                }
            }

            try     {
                btSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onPause() and failed to close socket." + e2.getMessage() + ".");
            }
        }

        private void checkBTState() {

            if(btAdapter==null) {
                errorExit("Fatal Error", "Bluetooth Not supported. Aborting.");
            } else {
                if (btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                    Log.d("SEND BT SERIAL", "Bluetooth is enabled");
                } else {
                    Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(btAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                    startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
                }
            }
        }

        private void errorExit(String title, String message){
            Toast msg = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    title + " - " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            msg.show();
            finish();
        }

        private void sendData(String message) {
            byte[] msgBuffer = message.getBytes();

            Log.d("SEND BT SERIAL", "Sending data: " + message + "");

            try {
                outStream.write(msgBuffer);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                String msg = "In onResume() and an exception occurred during write: " + e.getMessage();
                if (address.equals("00:00:00:00:00:00"))
                    msg = msg + ".\n\nUpdate your server address.";
                msg = msg +  ".\n\nCheck that the SPP UUID: " + MY_UUID.toString() + " exists on server.\n\n";

                //errorExit("Fatal Error", msg);
            }
        }
    }


//and my layout


<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_dark">
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:background="@android:color/background_dark">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgLogo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@drawable/contilogo"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/parking_mode_description"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#FFF"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="@string/mode_prompt"
            android:textColor="#FFF"/>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:entries="@array/parking_options"
            android:prompt="@string/mode_prompt"
            android:theme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_ledControl"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="LED CONTROL"
            android:textColor="#faa61a"
            android:background="@android:color/background_dark"/>

        <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right" >
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_next"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:text="@string/text_next"
                android:textColor="#faa61a"
                android:background="@android:color/background_dark" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: What is your precise question? Where would you like that `switch`? You just exposed almost 300 lines of code here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do something like this. when switching views dynamically like this i suggest looking into fragments.

```
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
    switch (positiion) {
        case 0:  loadView1();
                 break;
        case 1:  loadView2();
                 break;
        case 2:  loadView3();
                 break;
   }
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
    // your code here
}

});
```